# SSO and SSL Certificates

Tags: ssl, single-sign-on

I was ask to use a different SSL certificate for my SSO web service and a different SSL certificate for my website.

Why would I need a different SSL certificate when both the website and webservice are under the same IIS?

Answer (score 4):

Usually certificates are issued to a particular domain. If your website and webservice are on different sub domains then you would use a different certificate for each.
Alternatively you can obtain wildcarded certificates (ie. *.yourdomain.com) but these tend to be much more expensive.